# getSheetByName() returns null in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to try and set the sheet title to the name of the form that I have just connected to it with the code. However, I keep getting that the sheet name returning as "null", even though the debugger and physically looking at the sheet indicate that the name (Form Responses 1) is there. Any suggestions?

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.create('C Term 2017 Unit 0');
var idlog = data.getId();
var title = 'RST.5'; 

for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
var dataset = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idlog);
var sname = ('Form Responses ' + i);
var active = dataset.getSheetByName(sname);
active.setName(title); 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please checkout [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
var sname = ('Form Responses ' + i);
```

add

```
var i = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. This code is a small piece inside a fairly large code that would have been impractical to post. The var i defined before a loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the variable i is not correctly converted to a string?
You could try converting i to string explicitly:

```
var sname = ('Form Responses ' + i.toString());
```